# FluentNHibernate base ClassMap<T> and avoiding the use of typeof(T) to determine entity ID type for defining NHibernate generator

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

To centralize some of my logic for each FluentNHibernate class mapping (specifically for mapping auditing properties and the actual primary ID), I've got a base ClassMap called AuditedEntityClassMap which is something like the following:

```
public class AuditedEntityClassMap<TEntity, T> : ClassMap<TEntity> where TEntity : AuditedPersistentObject<T>
{
    public AuditedEntityClassMap()
    {
        Cache.ReadWrite();
        DynamicUpdate();
        ApplyId();
        this.ChangeAuditInfo();
    }

    protected virtual void ApplyId()
    {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
                map.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo(HiLoConstants.NHibernateHiLoTable, HiLoConstants.NHibernateHiLoColumn, HiLoConstants.NHibernateHiLoMaxLo);
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Guid))
                map.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            else
                throw new InvalidIdTypeInClassMappingException("Invalid type set in class mapping: " + typeof(T));
    }
}
```

My question is that the type checking of the generic in order to determine the type of NHibernate generator mapping that should be used for it smells and I'm wondering if there's a better way of dealing with it.

1. The generic type for my domain entities' IDs is used throughout and works great everywhere else (and it's used extensively).
2. I'd prefer not to have to define the ID mapping in every entity's ClassMap if I can avoid it. If this is the only way to do so, I'll live with it.

Thoughts and suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's nothing better than what I've got now.

Answer (score 0):

I' could not get your code to compile, but I am surprised it works.

Wouldn't T be the DataClass instead of the id.

An other way I can thing of is with reflection but I can't imagine that to be much better way.

You could get the properties of T with reflection and search for a property named Id or id.
And then get the type of that property. But I don't know how you would call Map in this context.

```
var pp = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "Id").FirstOrDefault();
if (pp != null)
{
  if (pp.PropertyType.Name == "Int64" || pp.PropertyType.Name == "Int32")
  {
    Map();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt response. I deleted it soon after posting but I guess after you saw it and started replying. Yes, the syntax was incorrect and has since been updated.

Comment: Throwing in reflection in there would be even smellier in my mind. The smell in my mind has to do with treating the generic as no longer generic this far along in the chain which defeats the point of having it be generic in the first place (apart from the fact that it's invaluable everywhere else in that chain).

Comment: In previous iterations I've simply done an AuditedEntityClassMapOfGuid, AuditedEntityClassMapOfInt, etc. and just set the inheriting class as applicable. But I liked that even less.

Comment: "treating the generic as no longer generic this far along in the chain which defeats the point of having it be generic in the first place"

I tried reading this but my head exploded :)

It' probably best if you find a different approach, this can only get smellier

Comment: Thanks yavosh. If there's no other way then I think I'll leave it as is. If it was dealing with an infinite number of types, I'd have a problem. But as it is, two types, possibly three, it's all good.